# Angular Overlay withTransformOriginOn usage

Tags: angularjs, angular, overlay

I need to animate a tooltip that uses Angular Overlay CDK, based on it's position.

`withTransformOriginOn` sounds like it could do the trick based on the [Angular Overlay CDK documentation](https://beta-angular-material-io.firebaseapp.com/cdk/overlay/api) :

[Angular withTransformOriginOn only documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7smC.png)

I do not understand how to use it, as Angular provides no example or description for the usage, and I can't find any example online...

Has anyone used it before and could point me to some direction, or explain to me how it is supposed to work ?

Thank you

Comment: did you try using a selector?
any selector such as css class selector: ".my-class" or "#my-id" as inputs to the function. i.e.
position().withScrollableContainers('#my-id')